# Есть ли какая-нибудь функция на частичное совпадение в switch-case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть форма, передающая в качестве `key` названия полей, мне нужно отсортировать эти поля, что бы все `question` были в группе.

Также есть `switch`:

```
switch (key) {
    case 'cv':
        return ...
    case 'question_':
        return ...
    default:
        return ...
}
```

Как написать правильно кейс, чтоб он выполнил действие для всех `question_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам простой пример

```js
const questions = {cv: '', abc: '.', question_1: '', question_23: ''};

function processKeys(questions) {
  return Object.keys(questions).map(key => {
    const checkedKey = key.includes('question_') ? 'question_' : key;
    switch (checkedKey) {
      case 'cv':
        return 'cv';
      case 'abc':
        return '.';
      case 'question_':
        return 'question_';
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
}

console.log(processKeys(questions));
```

Comment: даже не знаю, чем ваш ответ отличается от моего, кроме того, что я поддержал и другие ключи)

Comment: автору вопроса виднее)

Comment: Да и я особо не понял что с Вашим ответом не так.

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить ключи на группы и смотреть уже по группам

```js
const questions = {cv: '', abc: '.', question_1: '', question_23: ''}

const getQuestionGroup = (key) => {
  if (key.includes('question')) return 'question';
  if (key.includes('abc')) return 'abc';
  if (key.includes('cv')) return 'cv';
}

const processQuestion = (questions, key) => {
  const questionGroup = getQuestionGroup(key);
  switch (questionGroup) {
    case 'cv':
      console.log('cv group');
      break;
    case 'question':
      console.log('question group');
      break;
    case 'abc':
      console.log('abc group');
      break;
    default: console.log('oops!'); break;
  }
}

processQuestion(questions, 'abc');
processQuestion(questions, 'question_1');
processQuestion(questions, 'cv');
processQuestion(questions, 'question_23');
```

*надеюсь у вас не будет `question_abc`*

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Я бы хотела узнать вариант компактнее

Answer (score -1):

В общем, сделала вариант такой:

```
        if (key.includes('question_')) {
          ...
        } else {
          switch (key) {
            case 'cv':
               return ...
            default:
               return ...
        } 
    }
```

Но если у кого есть идея, как избавиться от if, буду рада)

Comment: Вы делаете тоже самое, что сделал @ThisMan, за исключением, что у вас кроме как `question_` больше ничего не будет. Но вот хоть убейте, я не понимаю, зачем эти костыли, когда есть цикл и есть банальные модули, что упростит жизнь в 10 раз, чем ваш велик с квадратными колесами. Банально форма отправляет массив своих полей, ваши поля, есть строки, через `indexOf` проверяем вхождение, делаем вызов нужного действия. ПРОФИТ!

Comment: @And не понимаю, откуда столько агрессии? я еще не успела разобраться с indexOf. Возможно, Вы правы. Я ж с Вами не спорю. Просто мне не нужна дополнительная функция, проверяющая все поля на включаемость имен, ведь у полей могут быть похожие имена (о чем он сам упомянул), ну и если у меня таких полей будет 100, мне писать 100 строчек в его функции, а потом 100 строчек в основной?

Comment: Какая агрессия, вы о чем? Уважаемая, вы сначала научитесь формулировать свои вопросы. К тому-же, ответ @Doigrales, делает сугубо тоже самое, что делает @ThisMan, только еще добавил циклическую функцию и не понятно зачем `Object.keys`...  Ну и конечно-же, тернарный оператор, который также является `if-else`.

Comment: @And почему-то только Вы один не поняли сути вопроса. А человек взял и ответил спокойно и правильно, и до Вашего исправления

Comment: Ответили по вопросу, но в итоге, вопрос в другом. Есть форма которая отправляет ключи, эти ключи есть массив. И оказывается у вас уже есть цикл и есть разбор. И это мне пришлось выяснить, но суть не в этом, а совсем в другом, я так понимаю. что в `switch'e` вы пытаетесь опять наверно создавать массив уже с найдеными `question_*` и делать из них массив группу или нет? Что дальше то вы делаете! Это не понятно вообще. Если вы делаете из этого опять массив, то возьмите `filter`, и там в пару строк весь ваш код будет, который отфильтрует вам все массивы и сделает вам все группы.

Comment: @And в том то и дело, что вопрос был именно в том, на что ответили. Я не создаю больше никакого массива, я просто разбиваю их на группы для редакса. Я вот не понимаю, зачем Вам это так необходимо понять!? Вопрос задан четко, четко на него получен ответ, мне важен был switch, решение правда оказалось легким, просто меня занесло не туда, так бы и вопроса не было